# Could anyone please help me with this c program coding?

Tags: c, reverse

i have got a program to do as my homework. the program is simple. it asks to reverse the digits entered by the user and then print it using while loop. the problem arises when the user enters a number starting with zeroes.

For example:

```
Enter the number: 0089
The reversed number is : 9800
```

This is how the output should be. instead i get "98" as the answer.

and thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint, it doesn't matter that the characters entered represent a number. You can just read characters.

Comment: read number as string !

Comment: Though this question has been putted on hold, look at my answer: it makes exactly what you want, Sachin Nandakumar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than reading the 0089 input as a numeric value, read it as a character array. This way the zeros won't be removed.

Comment: You are right. It is simple math rule 0089 = 89

Answer (score 5):

When asked to do someone else's homework, I like to devise an obtuse and compact way to do it.

```
void reverseNumber(void)
{
    char c;
    ((c=getchar()) == '\n')? 0 : reverseNumber(), putchar(c);
}
```

Comment: But the homework clearly asked for a "while loop." They don't learn recursion until the second week of class.

Comment: Kudos for using the comma operator to really make it really obtuse!

Answer (score 1):

Read the numbers as a string.

And then use `atoi()` (stdlib.h) to make an integer number out if the string:

```
/* int atoi (const char *) */
```

**Here is working code that makes exactly what your question requires:**

```
//  input: 0321
// output: 1230

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[80] = {0}, temp_str[80] = {0};
    int num, i, length = 0, temp_length = 0;

    printf("Enter a reversed number (e.g. 0089): ");
    scanf("%s", str);

    length = strlen(str);
    temp_length = length;

    printf("string_length: %d\n", length);
    for ( i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        temp_str[i] = str[temp_length - 1]; 
            /* The string length is 4 but arrays are [0][1][2][3] (you see?),
               so we need to decrement `temp_length` (minus 1) */ 
        temp_length--;
    }

    printf("temp_str: %s\n", temp_str);

    num = atoi(temp_str);
    printf("num:  %d\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why integer at all? Simply print the same digits back. You only have to validate that initial string had nothing but digits.

Comment: @aragaer, If I understood the question properly, he have to enter the number in another order `0089`. He can `enter a string`. Then he can use function `atoi()` to make an integer number from the string. So `value = atoi (const char *pointer_to_the_string_he_entered)`

Comment: He has to reverse digits entered by user. So he has to - first - verify that he got only digits and - second - reverse them. Nowhere it says about number at all.

Comment: @aragaer, I'm trying to write some code. It'll take some minutes

Comment: And now try it with "abc1234def" and you'll get ... 0. Instead of an error message.

Comment: @aragaer, I appreciate your help but the question was about **hot to make 9800 out of 0089?**. That is human-factor error if user enters "abc1234def". That is another question: Sachin Nandakumar hasn't asked **the problem is when I enter: abc1234def**.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35363/discussion-between-yulian-khlevnoy-and-aragaer)